# EF / Linq query with JOIN and GROUP

Tags: c#, sql, linq, frameworks, entity

I need to create the following TSQL query in EF/Linq but I am struggling :

```sql
SELECT mi.CategoryID, cat.Category
FROM tblPropertyMaintenanceItem mi
INNER JOIN tblCategory cat
ON cat.CategoryID = mi.CategoryID
WHERE mi.PropertyID = 451
GROUP BY mi.CategoryID, cat.Category
ORDER BY cat.Category
```

I have got a basic query working but that obviously give me duplicate lines :

```cs
var cats = context.MaintenanceItems
    .Include(s => s.Category)
    .Where(s => s.PropertyID == id)
    .OrderBy(s => s.Category.CategoryName).ToList();
```

How do I achieve what I need in SQL in Linq? I normally use SQL Stored Procs for data retrieval but trying to do this project all in EF/Linq.

Comment: Simple : var cats = context.MaintenanceItems
    .Include(s => s.Category)
    .Where(s => s.PropertyID == id)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .OrderBy(s => s.Category.CategoryName).ToList();

Comment: Show model classes and specify exactly what you need. Which fields. Because in LINQ query you are trying to retrieve whole Category with Maintenance Item.

Comment: Hi :
public class Category
{
  public int CategoryID { get; set; }
  public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

    public class MaintenanceItem
    {
        public int MaintenanceItemID { get; set; }
        public int PropertyID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }

I just want the unique CategoryID and CategoryName for the selected PropertyID. Sorry formatting does not work in these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that - initially it was generating an error :

The LINQ expression 'DbSet\r\n    .Where(m => m.PropertyID == __id_0)\r\n    .Join(\r\n        outer: DbSet, \r\n        inner: m => EF.Property<Nullable>(m, "CategoryID"), \r\n        outerKeySelector: c => EF.Property<Nullable>(c, "CategoryID"), \r\n        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<MaintenanceItem, Category>(\r\n            Outer = o, \r\n            Inner = i\r\n        ))\r\n    .GroupBy(\r\n        source: m => m.Inner, \r\n        keySelector: m => m.Outer)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I changed it slightly and now it seems to work :

```
 var cats = context.MaintenanceItems
            .Include(s => s.Category)
            .Where(s => s.PropertyID == id).AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
            .Select(x => x.First())
            .OrderBy(s => s.Category.CategoryName).ToList();
```

Got some reading to do to understand why!

Comment: Which EF Core version?

Answer (score 0):

that may be useful...

```
var cats = context.Categories
.Include(s => s.MaintenanceItems)
.Where(s => s.MaintenanceItems.Any(y => y.PropertyID == id))
.Select(s => new { s.CategoryID, s.CategoryName });
```

Comment: Hi - thanks - so almost the other way round - it's a bit like an IN query?

Comment: it can be said the opposite,Category table that interests you(CategoryID,CategoryName), therefore You have to select query in Category table